# How to organize client-side js in an express app?

Tags: javascript, express

In my app I have around 10 different pages, and most of them use some sort of JavaScript. Currently, I have one client-side `app.js` file that is included in all pages. In order to figure out what event listeners to attach on a page I  basically check `url` location and go from there:

```
window.onload = function () {
  let urlLocation = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]

  //Global functionality for all pages
  UIctrl.toggleActiveNavbar(urlLocation)

  //createTopic route
  if (urlLocation === 'createTopic' || urlLocation === 'edit') {
    UIctrl.createTopicTagsBasedOnCategory()
    UIctrl.handleCreateOrEditTopicClick()
  }

  if (urlLocation === 'editPost' || urlLocation === 'createPost') {
    UIctrl.handleCreateOrEditPostClick()
  }

 // .... and so on 

 }
```

Even though it works, I don't think it's a good way to do it. If a project becomes big enough, it's very hard to manage it.
I was not able to find an answer how to do it properly.  My questions are :

1. Should I have separate `js` files for each page ? My problem with this is that I have to duplicate common code that is used on all pages.
2. Do you use some sort of bundlers (webpack/parcel) in your express apps  that solve this issue? Maybe you could point me to a repository that shows how to set it up correctly.
3. How is this done in the real world production environments ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your choice of HTTP server is entirely independent of how you organise your client side code.

Comment: @Quentin Could you elaborate ? I'm not sure what you mean. My question is not about an HTTP server but about how to organize javascript on client-side in an express app.

Comment: Do you use some template system ? Do you split Controler for route from Model (data), Views from Templating. ? 

I've made some time ago small express page with mustache check this : https://github.com/robert8888/dj-truck-share-point

Comment: @robert I use `ejs`. Thanks I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition that comparing URLs to decide what initialization to run is a bad way to code is correct.  That is not a good pattern and will quickly get out of control with more and more pages and maintenance over time can get to be a real pain.

Instead, you can put common code in a shared JS file that every page loads so those functions are available as needed.  Then, use an inline `<script>` tag inside each individual page to do the page-specific initialization that sets up event listeners that are particular to that page and calls code in the shared JS file.

If for some pages, you have lots of page-specific initialization code, you could put just that page-specific code in a page-specific JS file, but in general you don't want to have an external JS file for every one of your pages if you can avoid it.  Try putting most of the code in the common JS file and then just using a small bit of inline code in each specific page to do the right initialization.  This puts most of your code in a common, shared JS file and keeps page-specific initialization logic in the specific page.

> Should I have separate js files for each page ? My problem with this is that I have to duplicate common code that is used on all pages.

No.  You don't want to duplicate lots of code in separate JS files as that is a maintenance nightmare and defeats effective browsing caching.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Let me paraphrase just to make sure that I understood you correctly. So, I can  put different functions that are used by different pages in common JS file, and than I can initialize what I need on each page by using inline script. Is that correct? Also,  I just checked my code, and I actually have 1-2 common functions for all pages, everything else is page specific at this point.

Comment: @Noob - Yes, that is one reasonable way to do it.